# Kubernetes: kubectl node01 notready

Tags: kubernetes

i am trying  to deploy a cluster of etcd+flanneld+kubernetes on CentOS machines. etcd and flanneld are running fine. But not kubernetes.

My environment:

```
coreos05: CentOS7 - 192.168.0.114
coreos08: CentOS7 - 192.168.2.57
```

ETCD:

```
[root@coreos05 ~]# etcdctl -C 192.168.0.114:4001 member list
e83ffc60b9b71862: name=coreos05 peerURLs=http://coreos05:2380,http://coreos05:7001 clientURLs=http://192.168.0.114:2379,http://192.168.0.114:4001
f877fb31ab0f7105: name=coreos08 peerURLs=http://coreos08:2380,http://coreos08:7001 clientURLs=http://192.168.2.57:2379,http://192.168.2.57:4001
[root@coreos05 ~]# etcdctl -C 192.168.2.57:4001 member list
e83ffc60b9b71862: name=coreos05 peerURLs=http://coreos05:2380,http://coreos05:7001 clientURLs=http://192.168.0.114:2379,http://192.168.0.114:4001
f877fb31ab0f7105: name=coreos08 peerURLs=http://coreos08:2380,http://coreos08:7001 clientURLs=http://192.168.2.57:2379,http://192.168.2.57:4001
```

INTER-NODE COMMUNICATIONS BETWEEN ECTD AND FLANNELD:

```
[root@coreos05 ~]# netstat -putona | egrep 'etcd|flanneld' |grep 2.57
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.114:4001      192.168.2.57:42996      ESTABLISHED 16288/etcd           keepalive (14,65/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.114:2380      192.168.2.57:32817      ESTABLISHED 16288/etcd           off (0.00/0/0)
[root@coreos05 ~]#
```

STATUS OF ALL SERVICES IN THE MASTER:

```
[root@coreos05 ~]# for SERVICES in etcd flanneld kube-apiserver kube-controller-manager kube-scheduler; do systemctl status $SERVICES ; done
    etcd.service - Etcd Server
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/etcd.service; enabled)
       Active: active (running) since mar 2015-05-12 11:54:16 CEST; 33min ago
     Main PID: 16590 (etcd)
       CGroup: /system.slice/etcd.service
               └─16590 /usr/bin/etcd

    may 12 11:54:16 coreos05 etcd[16590]: 2015/05/12 11:54:16 raft: e83ffc60b9b71862 became follower at term 46
    may 12 11:54:16 coreos05 etcd[16590]: 2015/05/12 11:54:16 raft: newRaft e83ffc60b9b71862 [peers: [], term: 46, commit: 5235, applied: 0, lastindex: 5235, lastterm: 46]
    may 12 11:54:16 coreos05 etcd[16590]: 2015/05/12 11:54:16 etcdserver: added local member e83ffc60b9b71862 [http://coreos05:2380 http://coreos05:7001] to cluster 85bb0f76f652d0f6
    may 12 11:54:16 coreos05 etcd[16590]: 2015/05/12 11:54:16 etcdserver: added member f877fb31ab0f7105 [http://coreos08:2380 http://coreos08:7001] to cluster 85bb0f76f652d0f6
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 etcd[16590]: 2015/05/12 11:54:17 raft: e83ffc60b9b71862 [term: 46] received a MsgVote message with higher term from f877fb31ab0f7105 [term: 47]
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 etcd[16590]: 2015/05/12 11:54:17 raft: e83ffc60b9b71862 became follower at term 47
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 etcd[16590]: 2015/05/12 11:54:17 raft: e83ffc60b9b71862 [logterm: 46, index: 5235, vote: 0] voted for f877fb31ab0f7105 [logterm: 46, index: 5235] at term 47
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 etcd[16590]: 2015/05/12 11:54:17 raft.node: e83ffc60b9b71862 elected leader f877fb31ab0f7105 at term 47
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 etcd[16590]: 2015/05/12 11:54:17 rafthttp: starting client stream to f877fb31ab0f7105 at term 47
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 etcd[16590]: 2015/05/12 11:54:17 etcdserver: published {Name:coreos05 ClientURLs:[http://192.168.0.114:2379 http://192.168.0.114:4001]} to cluster 85bb0f76f652d0f6
    flanneld.service - Flanneld overlay address etcd agent
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/flanneld.service; enabled)
       Active: active (running) since mar 2015-05-12 11:54:17 CEST; 33min ago
     Main PID: 16611 (flanneld)
       CGroup: /system.slice/flanneld.service
               └─16611 /usr/bin/flanneld -etcd-endpoints=http://192.168.0.114:4001 -etcd-prefix=/kuberdock/network/ --iface=enp3s0

    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 systemd[1]: Starting Flanneld overlay address etcd agent...
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 flanneld[16611]: I0512 11:54:17.024119 16611 main.go:247] Installing signal handlers
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 flanneld[16611]: I0512 11:54:17.025078 16611 main.go:205] Using 192.168.0.114 as external interface
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 flanneld[16611]: I0512 11:54:17.868493 16611 subnet.go:83] Subnet lease acquired: 10.10.93.0/24
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 flanneld[16611]: I0512 11:54:17.869081 16611 main.go:215] UDP mode initialized
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 flanneld[16611]: I0512 11:54:17.869106 16611 udp.go:239] Watching for new subnet leases
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 flanneld[16611]: I0512 11:54:17.871602 16611 udp.go:264] Subnet added: 10.10.65.0/24
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 systemd[1]: Started Flanneld overlay address etcd agent.
    kube-apiserver.service - Kubernetes API Server
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kube-apiserver.service; enabled)
      Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kube-apiserver.service.d
               └─pre-start.conf
       Active: active (running) since mar 2015-05-12 11:54:17 CEST; 33min ago
         Docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
     Main PID: 16690 (kube-apiserver)
       CGroup: /system.slice/kube-apiserver.service
               └─16690 /usr/bin/kube-apiserver --logtostderr=true --v=0 --etcd_servers=http://coreos05:4001 --address=0.0.0.0 --port=8080 --kubelet_port=10250 --allow_privileged=false --portal_net=10.10.0.0/16 --admission_control=Namespac...

    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 kube-apiserver[16690]: E0512 11:54:17.985524   16690 reflector.go:123] Failed to list *api.Namespace: Get http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/v1beta3/namespaces: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: connection refused
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 kube-apiserver[16690]: I0512 11:54:17.986149   16690 master.go:236] Will report 192.168.0.114 as public IP address.
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 kube-apiserver[16690]: E0512 11:54:17.987132   16690 reflector.go:123] Failed to list *api.LimitRange: Get http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/v1beta3/limitranges: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: connection refused
    may 12 11:54:17 coreos05 kube-apiserver[16690]: E0512 11:54:17.987437   16690 reflector.go:123] Failed to list *api.ResourceQuota: Get http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/v1beta3/resourcequotas: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: connection refused
    may 12 11:54:18 coreos05 kube-apiserver[16690]: [restful] 2015/05/12 11:54:18 log.go:30: [restful/swagger] listing is available at https://192.168.0.114:6443/swaggerapi/
    may 12 11:54:18 coreos05 kube-apiserver[16690]: [restful] 2015/05/12 11:54:18 log.go:30: [restful/swagger] https://192.168.0.114:6443/swaggerui/ is mapped to folder /swagger-ui/
    may 12 11:54:18 coreos05 kube-apiserver[16690]: I0512 11:54:18.093361   16690 server.go:353] Serving read-only insecurely on 0.0.0.0:7080
    may 12 11:54:18 coreos05 kube-apiserver[16690]: I0512 11:54:18.093784   16690 server.go:390] Serving securely on 0.0.0.0:6443
    may 12 11:54:18 coreos05 kube-apiserver[16690]: I0512 11:54:18.100679   16690 server.go:418] Serving insecurely on 0.0.0.0:8080
    may 12 11:54:18 coreos05 kube-apiserver[16690]: I0512 11:54:18.925329   16690 server.go:400] Using self-signed cert (/var/run/kubernetes/apiserver.crt, /var/run/kubernetes/apiserver.key)
    kube-controller-manager.service - Kubernetes Controller Manager
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kube-controller-manager.service; enabled)
       Active: active (running) since mar 2015-05-12 11:54:18 CEST; 33min ago
         Docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
     Main PID: 16714 (kube-controller)
       CGroup: /system.slice/kube-controller-manager.service
               └─16714 /usr/bin/kube-controller-manager --logtostderr=true --v=0 --machines=coreos08

    may 12 12:26:48 coreos05 kube-controller-manager[16714]: I0512 12:26:48.282325   16714 nodecontroller.go:504] Evicting pods2: 2015-05-12 12:26:48.282313291 +0200 CEST is later than 2015-05-12 12:26:48.282311109 +0200 CEST + 4m20s
    may 12 12:26:53 coreos05 kube-controller-manager[16714]: I0512 12:26:53.468254   16714 nodecontroller.go:504] Evicting pods2: 2015-05-12 12:26:53.468242266 +0200 CEST is later than 2015-05-12 12:26:53.468240541 +0200 CEST + 4m20s
    may 12 12:26:58 coreos05 kube-controller-manager[16714]: I0512 12:26:58.677179   16714 nodecontroller.go:504] Evicting pods2: 2015-05-12 12:26:58.677166286 +0200 CEST is later than 2015-05-12 12:26:58.67716449 +0200 CEST + 4m20s
    may 12 12:27:03 coreos05 kube-controller-manager[16714]: I0512 12:27:03.778387   16714 nodecontroller.go:504] Evicting pods2: 2015-05-12 12:27:03.778376111 +0200 CEST is later than 2015-05-12 12:27:03.778374466 +0200 CEST + 4m20s
    may 12 12:27:08 coreos05 kube-controller-manager[16714]: I0512 12:27:08.879548   16714 nodecontroller.go:504] Evicting pods2: 2015-05-12 12:27:08.879537205 +0200 CEST is later than 2015-05-12 12:27:08.879535608 +0200 CEST + 4m20s
    may 12 12:27:13 coreos05 kube-controller-manager[16714]: I0512 12:27:13.980986   16714 nodecontroller.go:504] Evicting pods2: 2015-05-12 12:27:13.980974374 +0200 CEST is later than 2015-05-12 12:27:13.980972639 +0200 CEST + 4m20s
    may 12 12:27:19 coreos05 kube-controller-manager[16714]: I0512 12:27:19.574960   16714 nodecontroller.go:504] Evicting pods2: 2015-05-12 12:27:19.574947254 +0200 CEST is later than 2015-05-12 12:27:19.574945586 +0200 CEST + 4m20s
    may 12 12:27:24 coreos05 kube-controller-manager[16714]: I0512 12:27:24.699798   16714 nodecontroller.go:504] Evicting pods2: 2015-05-12 12:27:24.699787548 +0200 CEST is later than 2015-05-12 12:27:24.699785704 +0200 CEST + 4m20s
    may 12 12:27:29 coreos05 kube-controller-manager[16714]: I0512 12:27:29.876981   16714 nodecontroller.go:504] Evicting pods2: 2015-05-12 12:27:29.876968588 +0200 CEST is later than 2015-05-12 12:27:29.876966413 +0200 CEST + 4m20s
    may 12 12:27:34 coreos05 kube-controller-manager[16714]: I0512 12:27:34.988483   16714 nodecontroller.go:504] Evicting pods2: 2015-05-12 12:27:34.988471519 +0200 CEST is later than 2015-05-12 12:27:34.988469853 +0200 CEST + 4m20s
    kube-scheduler.service - Kubernetes Scheduler Plugin
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kube-scheduler.service; enabled)
       Active: active (running) since mar 2015-05-12 11:54:18 CEST; 33min ago
         Docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
     Main PID: 16734 (kube-scheduler)
       CGroup: /system.slice/kube-scheduler.service
               └─16734 /usr/bin/kube-scheduler --logtostderr=true --v=0

    may 12 11:54:18 coreos05 systemd[1]: kube-scheduler.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
    may 12 11:54:18 coreos05 systemd[1]: Unit kube-scheduler.service entered failed state.
    may 12 11:54:18 coreos05 systemd[1]: Starting Kubernetes Scheduler Plugin...
    may 12 11:54:18 coreos05 systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes Scheduler Plugin.
    may 12 11:54:18 coreos05 kube-scheduler[16734]: W0512 11:54:18.139880   16734 server.go:83] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using default API client.  This might not work.
    may 12 12:09:18 coreos05 kube-scheduler[16734]: E0512 12:09:18.150197   16734 reflector.go:158] watch of *api.Service ended with: very short watch
    may 12 12:09:18 coreos05 kube-scheduler[16734]: E0512 12:09:18.156710   16734 reflector.go:158] watch of *api.Node ended with: very short watch
    may 12 12:24:19 coreos05 kube-scheduler[16734]: E0512 12:24:19.154734   16734 reflector.go:158] watch of *api.Service ended with: very short watch
    may 12 12:24:19 coreos05 kube-scheduler[16734]: E0512 12:24:19.160947   16734 reflector.go:158] watch of *api.Node ended with: very short watch
```

NOTE errors in kube-apiserver.service

```
Failed to list *api.Namespace: Get http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/v1beta3/namespaces: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: connection refused
```

KUBECTL NODE STATUS:

```
 [root@coreos05 ~]# kubectl get node
    NAME       LABELS    STATUS
    coreos08   <none>    NotReady
```

Why nodes are not ready?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes you are using? Also, complete logs from journalctl for kubelet would be helpful.
I guess the problem was you with the kubeconfig flag try mentioning it explicitly in the kubelet service unit file

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three possible cases due to which you might be facing this issue. Whenever I have seen that one/more nodes are in Not ready state, I have observed that either the DNS is not configured properly or network plugin is not running or kubelet is not running.
Since I see that you are using flannel for networking and it is running properly, there problem can be due to the other two reasons.
Try the following to pin point the issue:

1. To check whether DNS is properly configured or not, run the following command:

   kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces

Check if the pods with the name kube-dns or coredns are running or not. If it's not running then this is the problem.

2. To check whether kubectl is running properly or not, run the following command:

   systemctl get status kubectl

If it is not running then we have found the problem.
We have to see the logs of kubectl and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

looking at your configuration, it looks like you are trying to run two kubernetes masters?

Please read into the documentation, a good start are the getting started guides:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/docs/getting-started-guides

Comment: i have 1 master + 1 node. Master run etcd flanneld kube-apiserver kube-controller-manager kube-scheduler and node run etcd flanneld kube-proxy kubelet docker.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the admission_control you pass to the apiserver. Please post the full service config you use for the apiserver. /etc/systemd/system/apiserver.service

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time @PJong. My config is: [/etc/kubernetes/apiserver](http://pastebin.com/SnYDVQvm) and [systemd kube-apiserver](http://pastebin.com/z5510VpX)

Comment: I think your problem is having 2 servers being the api-server. Kubernetes is supposed to have one api-server running only on the master node (sorry no reference)

Answer (score 0):

check the below entries for kubernetes

```
cd /etc/kubernetes,vim config
KUBE_MASTER="--master=http://<master_hostname>:8080" 
KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS="--etcd-servers=http://<master_hostnane>:2379"
```